# Why birthday distribution is not uniform.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, birthday

I was reading about [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Calculating_the_probability) and I found a statement that `real-life birthday distributions are not uniform since not all dates are equally likely` (last line of first paragraph of section 'calculating the probability').

Here I do not understand why `all dates are not equally likely`. Long time ago I read that every second 3 babies are born. On this basis I don't think that all dates are not equally likely.

Kindly help me understand what mistake I'm making? Thanks.

Comment: There are several reasons, why the days of birthday are not equally like. Some reasons and a visual demonstration of the distribution can be seen here: http://www.dailymail.co.uk/femail/article-2145471/How-common-birthday-Chart-reveals-date-rates.html In real life the presumptions often do not hold.

Comment: "every second 3 babies are born" is just a rough estimate. It might have happened that last second actually 4 babies were born, or 25 babies, or actually none.

Comment: Also, February 29 is -- for obvious reasons -- less common as a birthday than other dates in late February or early March.

Comment: With regard to current events: Leap seconds also mess with uniformity (ever so slightly)...

Comment: @Stefan: Apparently that only makes an expected difference of 3 in the whole world (though I think the average rate is currently just over 4) with a substantial probability that it was 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When someone says that a baby is born every *(instert a period of time)*, they actually mean that this is true on average.
It can happen in a small village that three babies are born on the same day.

Many of these deviations from the average get washed out if you have enough data.
But some things don't.
Several things affect when people are born.
A mother's physical and mental condition depend on periodically changing things like the weekly and yearly rhythm of her life.
People are not equally likely to mate at all times.
And you can probably find or think of many others.

Comment: Sir the birthday problem is on a set of n people in a group. Here we don't know anything about the individuals i.e. we don't know their background, their culture etc For example on this site users belong to different countries. Now suppose you randomly select n users. Now in this case I think that `all dates are equally likely`. Isn't it? Now take another group of n but only Americans. Here I can say that the dates are not equally likely because from this [chart](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/femail/article-2145471/How-common-birthday-Chart-reveals-date-rates.html) I can say 9 Sep is more likely.

Comment: @Singh, no. Some of the patterns are global, and therefore remain true even if you look at people from different continents.

Answer (score 5):

The cited statistic, "every second 3 babies are born" is just a rough average.  In truth, human birth rates are extremely seasonal (the weather having a dramatic effect on human behavior).  Here is a reference:

http://www.sas.upenn.edu/~valeggia/pdf%20papers/birth_seasonality.pdf

Comment: In addition to seasonal variation in birth rates, seasonal variation in infant mortality will further skew the birthday distribution among adults (or even school-age children) -- more in some countries than in others.

Comment: Very rough: the [World Bank estimates](http://wdi.worldbank.org/table/2.1) the world population at 7,207.7 million in 2014 and the crude birth rate at 19 per 1000 people in 2013, so an average of over 4 per second.

Comment: In the US birth rates are a little higher in summer and a little lower in winter (December is a bit higher than neighboring months). In many years, the largest variation is roughly ±8% from the annual average. compared to results from the slightly incorrect uniform assumption, the probability of no match for 20-30 randomly chosen people may differ by one digit in the second place.